# AWS Cognito and DynamoDB, Authentication with Many to Many Relationships

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I'm building an API in Node with Serverless on AWS.

There is a Many to Many Relationship between Projects and Users.

```
- Each User can have many projects
- Each Project can have many users
```

What is the best way to ensure that when a user makes a request the `projectID` that they are requesting belongs to them?

Authentication is handled by Cognito, in DynamoDB I have a Partition Key that holds the `cognitoIdentityId` and the Sort Key holds the `projectId`.

My current thinking is that each time the API is called, I check in DynamoDB for the Partition Key and the Sort Key and if that returns as true it means that the user has access to the project and I proceed with the other requests.

However, I'm not sure if this is particularly efficient or if there are better ways that this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup Global Secondary Indexes, one for querying base on userId and another base on projectId.  This will allows you to efficiently query for users base on projectId or vice versa.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html